# How to implement \p{L} in python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I was trying to match all the string that contain one word in any language. My search led me to \p{...} which was absent in python's Re module.
But I found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex. It should work with \p{...} commands.
Although it doesn't.

I tried parsing those lines:

```
7652167371  apéritif
78687   attaché
78687   époque
78678   kunngjøre
78678   ærbødig
7687    vår
12312   dfsdf
23123   322432
1321    23123
2312    привер
32211   оипвыола
```

With:

```
def Pattern_compile(pattern_array):
    regexes = [regex.compile(p) for p in pattern_array]
    return regexes

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for regexp in Pattern_compile(p_a):
            if regexp.search (line):
                print line.strip('\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_a = ['^\d+\t(\p{L}|\p{M})+$', ]
    main()
```

The result is only latin-character word:

```
12312   dfsdf
```

Comment: on a quick glance, you don't pass your regex parameter to the main function. Try def main(p_a): and in the last line main(p_a)

Comment: But if p_a is empty, everything should match - as everything matches the empty regex.

Comment: I usually use re2 from Google, it's more powerful although I don't know if it cover what you need. [Re2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/)

Comment: Thanks Pizza, maybe i'll give it a try. And about main(p_a) - i'm new to python but isn't a global variable that should work in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass unicode. (Both regular expression and the string)

```
import sys

import regex


def main(patterns):
    patterns = [regex.compile(p) for p in patterns]
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.decode('utf8')
        for regexp in patterns:
            if regexp.search (line):
                print line.strip('\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([ur'^\d+\t(\p{L}|\p{M})+$', ])
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helped. I always wrote just r"" in regex before. And i guess i should always check with decode('utf-8') cause it's often a problem. Although i had to use line1 = line.decode('utf8'), otherwise the UnicodeEncodeError has been thrown.

Comment: @Derlin, Question is tagged `python-2.7`. BTW, you'd better to comment OP's question so that OP can notice.

Comment: How should you make this work on Python 3? I am getting bad scape \p if I do with just the `r` and SyntaxError if I do it with `ur`

Comment: @srcolinas, `r'...'`, `ur''...` ([Python 3.3+ support u'unicode' syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html)) both should work. BTW, make sure you're using `regex` (not `re`).

Comment: Thanks! I was using `re` . In any case `ur' '` is not valid syntax in Python 3.7

Comment: Oh, you're right. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/