# Why is "\p{L}" not working in this regex?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, jython

OS: Windows 7.  Jython 2.7.0 "final release".

```
for token in sorted_cased.keys():
    freq = sorted_cased[ token ]
    if freq > 1:
        print( 'token |%s| unicode? %s' % ( token, isinstance( token, unicode ), ) )
        if re.search( ur'\p{L}+', token ):
            print( '  # cased token |%s| freq %d' % ( token, freq, ))
```

`sorted_cased` is a dict showing the frequency of occurrence of tokens.  Here I'm trying to weed out the words (unicode characters only) which occur with frequency > 1.  (NB I was using `re.match` rather than `search` but `search` should detect event 1 such \p{L} in `token`)

sample output:

```
token |Management| unicode? True
token |n| unicode? True
token |identifiés| unicode? True
token |décrites| unicode? True
token |agissant| unicode? True
token |tout| unicode? True
token |sociétés| unicode? True
```

None is recognising that it has a single [p{L}] in it.  I've tried all sorts of permutations: double-quotes, adding `flags=re.UNICODE`, etc.

***later***
I have been asked to explain why this cannot be classed as a duplicate of [How to implement \p{L} in python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595979/how-to-implement-pl-in-python-regex).  It CAN, but... the answers in that other question do not draw attention to the need to use the **REGEX MODULE** (old version? very new version? NB they are different) as opposed to the **RE MODULE**.  For the sake of saving the hair follicles and sanity of future people who come up against this one, I request that the present paragraph be allowed to remain, albeit the question be "duped".

Also my attempt to install Pypi regex module **FAILED UNDER JYTHON** (using pip).  Probably better to use java.util.regex.

Comment: Python re module does not support `\p{L}` shorthand Unicode category class.

Comment: use `regex` module..

Comment: Thanks to you both!  I was flummoxed because there is indeed a python question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595979/how-to-implement-pl-in-python-regex using \p{L} ... and, yes, *regex* (a module I had never heard of!)

Comment: Another alternative is to restrict `\w` class like `(?![\d_])\w` and use a re.UNICODE flag. [*If UNICODE is set, this `\w` will match the characters \[0-9_\] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.*](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for that.  I have now installed the regex module.  But I'm not sure whether it's the old or the new ... the new appears to be very very new: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex.  That other question I referenced is presumably using the old one...

Comment: When using regex module, to make `\p{L}` match all Unicode letters, you need to make sure you pass a Unicode pattern string (by default, if no `L` or `U` flags are passed, the pattern encoding is used to detect the mode). *If neither the ASCII, LOCALE nor UNICODE flag is specified, it will default to UNICODE if the regex pattern is a Unicode string and ASCII if it’s a bytestring.*

Comment: Reopened since the suggested PyPi `regex` module in the linked dupe does not install in Jyphon and there are other Jyphon-specific solutions to the current problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to Java `java.util.regex`, the best option is to use the in-built `\p{L}` class.

Python (including the Jython dialect) does not support `\p{L}` and other Unicode category classes. Nor the POSIX character classes.

Another alternative is to restrict `\w` class like `(?![\d_])\w` and use a `UNICODE` flag. [*If `UNICODE` is set, this `\w` will match the characters [0-9_] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.*](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). This alternative has one flaw: it cannot be used inside a character class.

Another idea is to use `[^\W\d_]` (with `re.U` flag) that will match any char that is not a non-word (`\W`), digit (`\d`) and `_` char. It will effectively match any Unicode *letter*.

Comment: Thanks... but... !  I have just realised that my attempt to install the Pypi regex module failed.  This may be because I am using Jython rather than CPython.  Jythonistas probably need to admit "pythonic defeat" at this point and use Java classes instead: java.util.regex

Comment: Java's regex module has support for all POSIX classes via `\p` syntax, and you can use `\pP` there instead of `\p{P}`.

Comment: Actually, there is no flaw in `(?![\d_])\w` construction, since you can actually include more in the `\w` part and exclude more in the look-ahead part. Nothing prevents you from doing so.