# RegEx for capturing Korean alphabets

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, cjk, regex-greedy

My data frame in name is like below:

```
'가락시장(340)',
'가락시장(8)',
'가산디지털단지(7)',
'강남(222)',
'강남구청',
'강동',
'강동구청',
'강변(214)',
'개롱',
'개화산',
'거여',
'건대입구(212)',
'건대입구(7)',
'경복궁(317)',
'경찰병원(341)',
'고덕',
'고려대',
'고속터미널(329)',
'고속터미널(7)',
'공덕(5)',
'공덕(6)',
'공릉',
'광나루',
...
```

All list is in this [link](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/930798447a538c41455b54e6bc29bc8b)

#### Desired Output:

```
가락시장
가산디지털단지
강남
강남구청
강동
강동구청
강변
개롱
개화산
거여
건대입구
경복궁
경찰병원
고덕
고려대
고속터미널
공덕
공릉
광나루
```

#### Attempt

```
import re

for i in df['name']:
    i = re.match('^[가-힣]*$', i) # '^[가-힣]&$ is extract Hangeul (Korean alphabet)
```

But `df['name']` does not change.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might be able to capture your desired output with a simple expression, with only a `'` as a left boundary, then collecting the letters, similar to:

```
'([\p{L}]+)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"'([\p{L}]+)"

test_str = ("'가락시장(340)',\n"
    " '가락시장(8)',\n"
    " '가산디지털단지(7)',\n"
    " '강남(222)',\n"
    " '강남구청',\n"
    " '강동',\n"
    " '강동구청',\n"
    " '강변(214)',\n"
    " '개롱',\n"
    " '개화산',\n"
    " '거여',\n"
    " '건대입구(212)',\n"
    " '건대입구(7)',\n"
    " '경복궁(317)',\n"
    " '경찰병원(341)',\n"
    " '고덕',\n"
    " '고려대',\n"
    " '고속터미널(329)',\n"
    " '고속터미널(7)',\n"
    " '공덕(5)',\n"
    " '공덕(6)',\n"
    " '공릉',\n"
    " '광나루',")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CMNPHS/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

#### Reference

[How to implement \p{L} in python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595979/how-to-implement-pl-in-python-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove parentheses and parenthesized characters with the following code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\(\w*\)')
for text in YOUR_DATA_LIST : 
    only_station_name = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
    print(only_station_name)
```